# Flow Modeling in Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: transactions

I have deployed a smart-contract which is basically a money sending application. The established frontend asks user address [from] and the [to] address. When the amount is given the smart-contract initiates with the Metamask wallet for approval. I am testing it in the Rinkeby network.

What I am trying to achieve here is to create an anomaly detection tool based on profiles. Therefore I need to extract the transactional logs of the deployed smart contract continuously.

The sequence of my project is given below:

1- Extracting the data constantly to elastic search so the transactional logs must be up to date all the time 
2- Then extract the data constantly to my python backend.
3 - Analyze the data on a profile (address) basis. 
4- Creating a dashboard for smart-contracts insights.

How do I constantly extract (For instance the data should be updated every 5 minutes) data from Ethereum and inject into elastic search?

Also the transactional data originally in .JSON how do I change it to the .csv format with the regarding parameters.

I am going to analyze the smart contract data in python backend every 5 minutes and update to the dashboard.

Would you please help what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to contract events:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events

This can be easily done in Python or JavaScript.

Then you connect to your Ethereum Node over Websocket and run it in subscription mode, so that any new events emitted by the contract come to your event loop at the momement they are mined.